# Change the order of numbers in a list without creating a new one

Tags: python, list, math

I have a list with a sequence of numbers, for instance [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
I have to swap it in a way, so the list will be repacked like this:
[1,10,2,9,3,8,4,7,5,6]
So, the last goes after the first, the second-to-last after the second etc.
I cat do with creating a new list:

```
seq = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
def repack(seq):
    new_seq = []
    while len(seq):
        new_seq.append(seq.pop(0))
        new_seq.append(seq.pop())
    return new_seq
```

But my question is how can i accomplish this without creating a new list? Perhaps doing something with list slicing..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the result is coming from:

```
[1,10,2,9,3,8,4,7,5,6]

 1,   2,  3,  4,  5  
   10,  9,  8,  7,  6
```

You can see that the first five items are [1,2,3,4,5], and then we insert [10, 9, 8, 7, 6] in position [1, 3, 5, 7, 9].

You can try this way:

```
>>> for i in range(5):
        item = a.pop()
        a.insert(i*2 + 1, item)
>>> a
[1,10,2,9,3,8,4,7,5,6]
```

Comment: thanks, very clear! I thought, that it is possible to do it like you did, but couldn't get with the index.